# JavaScript: How to disable buttons after clicking

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I have a question how can I upgrade my script that it can disable remaining buttons after you pressed five of them? Now it only count them.

My code:

```
<input type="Button" onclick="window.increment(event)" value="2"/>
<input type="Button" onclick="window.increment(event)" value="3"/>
<input type="Button" onclick="window.increment(event)" value="4"/>
<input type="Button" onclick="window.increment(event)" value="5"/>
<input type="Button" onclick="window.increment(event)" value="6"/>
<input type="Button" onclick="window.increment(event)" value="7"/>
<input type="Button" onclick="window.increment(event)" value="8"/>            
<div>
    <p>You've choose <a id="clicks">0</a> slot/s.</p>
</div>
```

Link to js:
https://jsfiddle.net/57js0ps7/6/

Comment: Your HTML isn't valid.  IDs cannot be duplicated in an HTML document.  Your buttons either need unique IDs, or no IDs.

Comment: Try adding `disabled` attribute to the button that you want to disable

Comment: Before we get that far, IDs must be unique

Comment: Tim Han I can't add that because at the begining every button needs to be active, then you choose five buttons and then remaining button need to disabled, so you can't choose more than five

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's as little as possible edited code that works but isn't that readable.

https://jsfiddle.net/90yw1buf/

HTML

```
<input type="Button" class="bt" onclick="window.increment(event)" value="1"/>
<input type="Button" class="bt" onclick="window.increment(event)" value="2"/>
<input type="Button" class="bt" onclick="window.increment(event)" value="3"/>
<input type="Button" class="bt" onclick="window.increment(event)" value="4"/>
<input type="Button" class="bt" onclick="window.increment(event)" value="5"/>
<input type="Button" class="bt" onclick="window.increment(event)" value="6"/>
<input type="Button" class="bt" onclick="window.increment(event)" value="7"/>
<input type="Button" class="bt" onclick="window.increment(event)" value="8"/>


<div>
    <p>You've choose <a id="clicks">0</a> slot/s.</p>
</div>
```

JS

```
window.increment = function(event) {
  var btn = event.target;
  btn.clicks = ((btn.clicks || 0) + 1) % 2;
  window.clicks = (window.clicks || 0) + btn.clicks * 2 - 1;
  document.getElementById("clicks").innerText = window.clicks;
  var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("bt");
  var i;
  if(window.clicks > 4) {
    for (i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
      if(buttons[i].clicks != 1) {
          buttons[i].disabled = true;
      } else {
        buttons[i].disabled = false;
      }
    }
  } else {
      for (i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
      buttons[i].disabled = false;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for?

```js
var clickedCount = 0;
var arr = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
function count (buttonNo) {
  if (arr[buttonNo-1] == 0) {
    clickedCount ++;
    arr[buttonNo-1] = 1
  }
  if (clickedCount >=5) {
    var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
    for (var i=0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
      if(arr[i]==0){
        buttons[i].disabled = 'disabled';
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
<button onclick="count(1)">button1</button>
  <button onclick="count(2)">button2</button>
  <button onclick="count(3)">button3</button>
  <button onclick="count(4)">button4</button>
  <button onclick="count(5)">button5</button>
  <button onclick="count(6)">button6</button>
  <button onclick="count(7)">button7</button>
  <button onclick="count(8)">button8</button>

</div>
```

Comment: it kinda work, but it need to disable remaining buttons not all of them

Comment: So the buttons already clicked, should be clickable even after the 5th Click?

Comment: I have edited the code snippet. Please check it out. If it delivers the desired output, please mark it as an correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try not to pollute the global scope (`window`) because it's a space that all the scripts on your page share, and you should keep shared space clean because you don't know what other scripts might assign a global variable called "click". Read up on closures and scope for some good ideas on how to avoid putting things in the global scope.

You should use classes instead of IDs because IDs must be unique, but classes don't have to be.

It's better to use `addEventListener` to put event listeners on your elements because an element can only have a single "onclick" function but they can have as many event listeners as they need.

Finally, don't use an anchor (`<a>`) tag unless it's intended to be clickable, and if it is, you need to include an `href` attribute`.

```js
(function(){
  var clicks = 0;
  var buttons = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("bt"));
  buttons.forEach(btn=>{
    btn.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
      clicks++;
      document.getElementById("clicks").innerText = clicks;
      btn.disabled = true;
      if(5 === clicks) buttons.forEach(b=>b.disabled = true); 
    }, false)
  });
})();
```

```html
<input type="Button" class="bt" value="2"/>
<input type="Button" class="bt" value="3"/>
<input type="Button" class="bt" value="4"/>
<input type="Button" class="bt" value="5"/>
<input type="Button" class="bt" value="6"/>
<input type="Button" class="bt" value="7"/>
<input type="Button" class="bt" value="8"/>            
<div>
    <p>You've choose <span id="clicks">0</span> slot/s.</p>
</div>
```